# How to write Any with Contains as an expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I write this

```
x => x.ListOfStrings.Any(x => x.Contains("foobar"))
```

as an expression? For

```
x => x.Contains("foobar")
```

I do this:

```
var contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) })!;

object? toCompare = value.GetString();

Expression.Call(property, contains, Expression.Constant(toCompare, property.Type));
```

I am not sure how to combine this with Any.

Answer (score 0):

`Reflection` isn't a good solution - I'm not sure if you are trying to shorten it or simply introduce a syntax sugar.

##### Syntax Sugar:

You can use an `extension method`:

```
public static class XExtensions
{
  public static bool Contains(this MyType x, string mahString)
  {
    return x.ListOfStrings.Any(s => s.Contains(mahString));
  }
}

// Call:
X x;
x.Contains("Hello");
```

This simply uses `static methods`.
The keyword `this` in a parameter turns it into `extension method` which you can call directly.
But the `MSIL` will simply call a static method.